# How to include another file through LPF file in Lattice Diamond tool?

Tags: fpga, synthesis, lattice-diamond

In Lattice Diamond FPGA synthesis tool, pin placement is specified through a LPF (extension  .lpf) file.

However, only a single LPF file can be active at a time.

Is it possible to include another LPF file through the active LPF file, so the LPF file configuration can be split in multiple files?

Comment: [LPF file format specification](https://github.com/danderson/ulxs/blob/main/lpf.md)" Annoyingly, it seems Lattice doesn't document the format, and instead forces you to use their proprietary design software to generate LPF files." Which might lead your readers to consider contacting Lattice.

Comment: Or the [User Guilde](https://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/1D/DiamondUserGuide34.ashx?document_id=50878) LPF Constraint Files "An implementation can have multiple .lpf files, but only one can be active at a time."

Comment: @user16145658: Thanks a lot for the references, in special the one "LPF file format specification".  Appears there are no way to include another LPF file.